# Data in dataSource is not refreshed when source is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui

I have dataSource in KendoUI that is connected with on click event. I mean - after click ID of the element is passed to function, which - based on the id - chooses proper url for dataSource.

**PROBLEM:**

I checked and url is passed correctly, everything works fine, BUT data for each user doesn't change. So for example if I click on user with id 1, I get 1.json, but when I click on user with id 2 I also get data from 1.json.

When I first click on user with id 2 I get 2.json and after I click on user with id 1 I get 2.json data.

HOW I can refresh this data?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to add, that function getData is in kendo.observable object. I thought that it might not be necessary to tell and I wanted to keep it as simple as possible, but.. well, obviously it's not that simple. Actual code:

```
var myModel = kendo.observable({
     getData: function(myDiv,id) {
        mySource.transport.options.read.url = id + '.json';
        mySource.fetch(function(){
            var data = this.data();
            var tree = $('<ul></ul>');    
            $.each(data, function(i,object) {
                $('<li>').html('<a href="">'+object.task_name+'</a>').appendTo(tree);
            });       
            tree.appendTo(myDiv);
        });
    }
};
```

and `getData()` is binded to click on div event ( mobile app ).

Comment: Try to demonstrate your case with jsbin example, everything looks right with the code.

Comment: I found solution. Don't know whether to add answer or edit my question?

Comment: Add answer and mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

maybe are you clearing myDiv each time as well? Otherwise you're just appending onto the end and not clearing the previous response, so while it is getting the right response you're not seeing it?

Comment: I think something is wrong with the data() part, in console it shows that proper source is being loaded. And I'm not clearing div, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you say url is passed correctly, probably the `this` reference in the callback doesn't return what's expected. If that's the case, this would fix it:

```
function getData(myDiv,id) {
    mySource.transport.options.read.url = id + '.json';
    var me = this;    //Check this
    mySource.fetch(function(){
        var data = me.data();   //And this
        var tree = $('<ul></ul>');    
        $.each(data, function(i,object) {
            $('<li>').html('<a href="">'+object.task_name+'</a>').appendTo(tree);
        });       
        tree.appendTo(myDiv);
    });
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: emm nope, it only shows right now that Object has no method 'data' .

Answer (score 0):

apparently fetch data remembers last response (?), so the solution that worked for me is:

```
var myModel = kendo.observable({
     getData: function(myDiv,id) {
        mySource.transport.options.read.url = id + '.json';
        mySource.read();
        mySource.one('change',function(){
            var data = this.data();
            var tree = $('<ul></ul>');    
            $.each(data, function(i,object) {
                $('<li>').html('<a href="">'+object.task_name+'</a>').appendTo(tree);
            });       
            tree.appendTo(myDiv);
        });
    }
};
```

yep, it's mySource.one, not 'on'.